# Oracle Apex How to generate value from the current id

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am new to Apex. But I already read through the documentation. But couldn't quite be in the page I wish to look.

So, how do I generate a value from the id in Apex form?

I have a table named customers where it has cust_id and member_id.
Now I want to generate the member_id based on the cust_id when user are to fill in the registration. The cust_id is sequenced.

As for example :
- the user are to be the third,so the cust_id is 3.(this value will not be accessible i guess as the cust_id will be generate after it been saved ).
- and now i want my member_id to have this kind alike value  : 20130003 ( 2013 is according to date and 0003 is the cust_id.

Can anyone please show me how to do it.

Note : 
- I want to have cust_id and member_id because customer have two type which is member or non-member.so for non-member,member_id will be null

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trigger

```
create or replace trigger bi_customers 
before insert into customers 
for each row
begin
select to_number(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY'))*10000+:new.cust_id into :new.member_id from dual;
end;
```

Comment: I'd probably recommend using a trigger too, if OP can live with the fact that the code will only be shown after a submit then. Also, you could use `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')||LPAD(:new.cust_id,4,0)` to get the new id.